# StackOverFlowException thrown only when multi-threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, md5, stack-overflow

I'm writing a program to help me gather statistics for a research report I'm writing on password security.  I decided to make the application run on multiple threads when attempted to brute-force an MD5 hashed password for the obvious performance increase.  The application runs fine on a single thread, but the moment 2 threads are running, a StackOverFlowException is throwing at "using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())" in the TryPass function.

```
    // Microsoft's GetMd5Hash function.
    static string GetMd5Hash(MD5 md5Hash, string input)
    {
        // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash. 
        byte[] data = md5Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input));

        // Create a new Stringbuilder to collect the bytes 
        // and create a string.
        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        // Loop through each byte of the hashed data  
        // and format each one as a hexadecimal string. 
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            sBuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
        }

        // Return the hexadecimal string. 
        return sBuilder.ToString();
    }

    static bool TryPass(string attempt, string password)
    {
        using (MD5 md5Hash = MD5.Create())
        {
            if (GetMd5Hash(md5Hash, attempt) == password)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }



    static bool BruteForce(BruteOptions bruteOptions)
    {
        if (bruteOptions.prefix.Length == 1 && TryPass(bruteOptions.prefix, bruteOptions.password)) // If it's the first in a series, try it.
            return true;

        for (int i = 0; i < bruteOptions.chars.Length; i++)
        {
            if (TryPass(bruteOptions.prefix + bruteOptions.chars[i], bruteOptions.password))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The password is: " + bruteOptions.prefix + bruteOptions.chars[i]);
                return true;
            }

            if (bruteOptions.prefix.Length + 1 < bruteOptions.maxLength)
                if (BruteForce(bruteOptions))
                    return true;

            //Console.WriteLine(prefix + chars[i]);
        }

        return false;
    }



    public struct BruteOptions
    {
        public string password, prefix;
        public char[] chars;
        public int maxLength;
    }

    static void OptionBruteForce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("----- Brute-Force -----");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");

        BruteOptions bruteOptions = new BruteOptions();
        bruteOptions.password = ReadString("Enter the MD5 password hash to brute-force: ");
        bruteOptions.chars = ReadString("Enter the characters to use: ").ToCharArray();
        bruteOptions.maxLength = ReadIntegerRange("Max length of password: ", 1, 16);
        bruteOptions.prefix = "";

        Stopwatch myStopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int NUM_THREADS = bruteOptions.chars.Length;
        Thread[] workers = new Thread[NUM_THREADS]; // Run a thread for each char.
        var countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(NUM_THREADS);
        bool result = false;

        // Start workers.
        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
        {
            int index = i;
            BruteOptions newBruteOptions = bruteOptions;
            newBruteOptions.prefix = bruteOptions.chars[index].ToString();

            workers[index] = new Thread(delegate()
            {
                // Also check single char.
                if (BruteForce(bruteOptions))
                {
                    result = true;

                    // End all other threads.
                    for (int ii = 0; ii < NUM_THREADS; ii++)
                    {
                        if (workers[ii].ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Running && index != ii) // Ensures we don't prematurely abort this thread.
                        {
                            workers[ii].Abort();
                            countdownEvent.Signal(); // Signal so we can zero it and continue on the UI thread.
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Signal the CountdownEvent.
                countdownEvent.Signal();
            });

            workers[index].Start();
        }

        // Wait for workers.
        countdownEvent.Wait();

        if (!result)
            Console.WriteLine("No Match.");

        Console.WriteLine("Took " + myStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");
    }
```

That's all the relevant code.  Any insight onto why this is happening would be greatly appreciated!  I'm completely stumped.  I attempted to specify a greater stack size when initialising each thread, to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `static bool BruteForce(BruteOptions bruteOptions)` is infinitely recursive: it calls itself if the length allows, with the same parameters:

```
if (bruteOptions.prefix.Length + 1 < bruteOptions.maxLength)
    if (BruteForce(bruteOptions))
```

`bruteOptions` remain the same as it was on the entry to the function.

As a solution you may use this code:

```
if (bruteOptions.prefix.Length + 1 < bruteOptions.maxLength)
{
    BruteOptions newOptions = bruteOptions;
    newOptions.prefix += bruteOptions.chars[i];
    if (BruteForce(newOptions))
        return true;
}
```

Plus, you pass `bruteOptions`, not `newBruteOptions` to the delegate you use in main function. Thus, your multithreading is not used, in fact. All your threads test the same passwords. Change it to `newBruteOptions`.

Additionally, don't assume anything about threads execution order. You assume that all workers are filled by the moment one finds a proper password, which can be wrong. You will then get a `NullReferenceException` in this line:

```
if (workers[ii].ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Running && index != ii) // Ensures we don't prematurely abort this thread.
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that!  I appreciate your help, thanks very much good sir!  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your single threaded code looked a little different.

I would lose the recursion.

Comment: The recursion is necessary for calculating each possible password combination.  Unless there's another way?

Comment: Recursion can always be replaced by a loop with custom stack.

Comment: How would I go about this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, here's an alternate implementation without the recursion and making a bit better use of the language constructs and frameworks available as part of .Net

```
class Program
{
    private static string StringFromIndexPermutation(char[] characters, int[] indexes)
    {
        var buffer = new char[indexes.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < buffer.Length; ++i)
        {
            buffer[i] = characters[indexes[i]];
        }

        return new string(buffer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Increments a set of "digits" in a base "numberBase" number with the MSD at position 0
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="buffer">The buffer of integers representing the numeric string</param>
    /// <param name="numberBase">The base to treat the digits of the number as</param>
    /// <returns>false if the number in the buffer has just overflowed, true otherwise</returns>
    private static bool Increment(int[] buffer, int numberBase)
    {
        for (var i = buffer.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if ((buffer[i] + 1) < numberBase)
            {
                ++buffer[i];
                return true;
            }

            buffer[i] = 0;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate all the permutations of some set of characters in a string from length 1 to maxLength
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="characters">The characters to permute</param>
    /// <param name="maxLength">The maximum length of the permuted string</param>
    /// <returns>The set of all permutations</returns>
    public static IEnumerable<string> Permute(char[] characters, int maxLength)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; ++i)
        {
            var permutation = new int[i + 1];
            yield return StringFromIndexPermutation(characters, permutation);

            while (Increment(permutation, characters.Length))
            {
                yield return StringFromIndexPermutation(characters, permutation);
            }
        }
    }

    static string ReadString(string message)
    {
        Console.Write(message);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static int ReadIntegerRange(string message, int min, int max)
    {
        Console.Write(message + "({0} - {1})", min, max);

        while(true)
        {
            var test = Console.ReadLine();
            int value;

            if (int.TryParse(test, out value))
            {
                return value;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }

    static void OptionBruteForce()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("----- Brute-Force -----");
        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");

        var password = ReadString("Enter the MD5 password hash to brute-force: ");
        var chars = ReadString("Enter the characters to use: ").Distinct().ToArray();
        var maxLength = ReadIntegerRange("Max length of password: ", 1, 16);

        var myStopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        var result = false;
        string match = null;
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var passwordBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password);
        var originalMd5 = MD5.Create();
        var passwordHash = originalMd5.ComputeHash(passwordBytes);
        var hashAlgGetter = new ConcurrentDictionary<Thread, MD5>();

        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(Permute(chars, maxLength), new ParallelOptions
            {
                CancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token
            }, test =>
            {
                var md5 = hashAlgGetter.GetOrAdd(Thread.CurrentThread, t => MD5.Create());
                var data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(test);
                var hash = md5.ComputeHash(data);

                if (hash.SequenceEqual(passwordHash))
                {
                    myStopWatch.Stop();
                    match = test;
                    result = true;
                    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
        }

        if (!result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No Match.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Password is: {0}", match);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Took " + myStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        OptionBruteForce();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks amazing, well done!  If I ever do a re-write in future, I'll definitely have to take a much closer look at this and give it a go.  Thanks for your addition!